# get all images from post content wordpress using regular expression

Tags: regex, wordpress

I need to get all images from the post content of wordpress post.

I am using

```
preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches);
```

It works fine for single image but for multiple images, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use greedy dot-star or greedy dot-plus. They will eat up all characters immediately and may leave no opportunity for another match:

```
<img.+?src=([\'"])([^\'"]+)\1
```

Comment: Instead of the `[^\'"]+` negated character class, it is advisable to use a lazy dot `.*?`, otherwise strings like  `src="New 'value'"` won't get matched.

Comment: If URL is not encoded (the case exampled by you) then checking for single quotes as starting delimiter for value holder is not true at all `src='New 'value''` and shouldn't be caught. So what is more advisable is using encoded version of a URL otherwise `src="[^"]+"` is enough. @WiktorStribiżew